# What does the "-rN" segment of this code do pytest.main(["-v", "--tb=line", "-rN", __file__])?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have just started learning pytest and was told to use the following code to launch pytest but given no explanation about what everything did.

```
[pytest.main(\["-v", "--tb=line", "-rN", __file__\])][1]
```

Between Google and the pytest website (https://docs.pytest.org/) I have figured out everything else, I just cannot find what the "-rN" segment does. When I run the test without that segment in the code, it seems to not have any difference. Can anyone provide any insights and hopefully some documentation I can study as well?

[Test result with full code segment.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fq9m8.jpg)

Test result with without the code segment in question

```
pytest.main(["-v", "--tb=line", __file__])
```

[Test Result without the code segment in question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIx7x.jpg)

The only difference that I can find is that it runs faster without the code segment in question.

Comment: Using the pytest link you provided, I found the command line arguments https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#id89 docs. It explains what `-rN` does. `-r` is the flag you’re looking for the `N` is the value passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the [command line reference](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#command-line-flags):

> ```
>   -r chars              show extra test summary info as specified by chars:
>                         (f)ailed, (E)rror, (s)kipped, (x)failed, (X)passed,
>                         (p)assed, (P)assed with output, (a)ll except passed
>                         (p/P), or (A)ll. (w)arnings are enabled by default
>                         (see --disable-warnings), 'N' can be used to reset
>                         the list. (default: 'fE').
> ```

Also see this page on [Managing pytest's output](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/output.html#producing-a-detailed-summary-report):

> Special characters for (de)selection of groups:
>
> - `a` - all except `pP`
> - `A` - all
> - `N` - none, this can be used to display nothing (since fE is the default)

so the flag `-rN` overrides defaults and any settings in a config file and explicitly tells pytest not to display any output.

Comment: What do you mean by display any output? 
I ask because of what I have already learned. The "-v" command tells Pytest to display verbose output and whether the "-rN" is there or not, the output is unchanged. Even when I remove the "-v" then with or without the "-rN" it does not change the output. Additionally, when I try to remove either the r or the N pytest complains.

Comment: well they'd need to be used together. N and r are not independent flags - N is the argument to the `r` flag. and I'm not sure exactly how the precedence works within pytest - if you're using both `-v` and `-rN` you're sending a lot of conflicting instructions to the command line.

Comment: Do you have any failing tests? `-rN` won't change anything otherwise (since it removes `fE` which means `failed` and `Error`).

Comment: So, if a test fails then that is when it kicks in? Let me make a test fail and see what happens.

Comment: The "--tb=line" code segment also seems to do nothing on my specific file. I am going to guess that this particular code segment is the same thing and is just there for a more universal thing that we will be able to use through multiple projects. Thank you very much for your answer and taking the time to respond to my additional questions.

Comment: Oh for sure many of pytest’s command line options only come into play in certain contexts such as when an error or warning occurs a or even when a keyboard interrupt occurs. So it’s definitely better to dig through the options descriptions and documentation to fully understand these rather than trying to understand them all with trial and error.